# Unknown shorthand flag: 'd' in -d

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to pull a docker image using the following command. It was suggested that I run this as a guide for docker config at my workplace.

Tried removing the `-d` out of the command, but now I get same error but with `-name` instead. I am using a Mac and I run the command on the terminal.

`docker pull mysql/mysql-server:5.7docker run -d --name=dev-mysql -p3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% mysql/mysql-server:5.7 --secure-file-priv=""`

I expect the image to be downloaded. But instead I get the mentioned error.

Comment: Have you tried reading your command? Why are you clashing two commands into one?

Answer (score 5):

Your command is two separated commands.

Try this (it will download the image):

```
docker pull mysql/mysql-server:5.7
```

Then (it will run the container):

```
docker run -d --name=dev-mysql -p3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD= -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% mysql/mysql-server:5.7 --secure-file-priv=""
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it.